# WARNING in Invalid background value at Ignoring. in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have angular 4 application which is running fine on my local machine with `ng server` but when I try to build an application for production with `ng build -- prod` then i am getting below error, not getting what wrong with the production run. Error is:-

```
WARNING in Invalid background value at 12864:14. Ignoring.
```

Full detailed error

```
ERROR in : Type ModalsComponent in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src/app/pages/ui-features/modals/modals.component.ts is part of the declarations 
of 2 modules: JobListModdule in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src/app/pages/joblist/joblist.module.ts and UiFeaturesModule in E:/Projects
/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src/app/pages/ui-features/ui-features.module.ts! Please consider moving ModalsComponent in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code
/app/src/app/pages/ui-features/modals/modals.component.ts to a higher module that imports JobListModdule in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src
/app/pages/joblist/joblist.module.ts and UiFeaturesModule in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src/app/pages/ui-features/ui-features.module.ts. You 
can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes ModalsComponent in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src/app/pages/ui-features/modals
/modals.component.ts then import that NgModule in JobListModdule in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src/app/pages/joblist/joblist.module.ts and
 UiFeaturesModule in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src/app/pages/ui-features/ui-features.module.ts.
```

**Note->** if i just simply use `ng build` then it's not throwing any error but in this case, application needs a long time to load – around 5 to 6 min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as the error says `ModalsComponent` (`modals.component.ts`) is declared in two modules `modals.component.ts is part of the declarations 
of 2 modules: JobListModdule ... and UiFeaturesModule`.

So it's better to create a shared module and import ModalsComponent there, again as the error suggests 

`You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes ModalsComponent in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src/app/pages/ui-features/modals
/modals.component.ts then import that NgModule in JobListModdule in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src/app/pages/joblist/joblist.module.ts and
 UiFeaturesModule in E:/Projects/Rudram Admin/Code/app/src/app/pages/ui-features/ui-features.module.ts.` Directly from docs https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules